# How to create custom launcher app in Android like Go launcher app and themes?

Tags: android, themes, launcher

I want to create an custom launcher with theme as per Go launcher functionality. Selecting theme will just change the themes installed
Please suggest an example.

Answer (score 1):

Check this examples:

1. Custom Launcher App: http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/
2. ApplicationLauncher:http://www.taywils.me/2011/07/05/buildanapplicationlauncherwithandroid.html

Comment: Thanks. but I am trying to do launcher as Go Launcher App functionality. As can download themes and apply with single launcher application

Comment: @user9 do u found any code for go launcher like app?